# VBA Excel Форматирование части текста созданного формулой

Tags: excel, vba

Имеется диапазон ячеек (C5:C550) в которых формулой выводятся значения исходя с данных других книг и листов.
1. Нужно часть текста ячейки, полученного с помощью формулы, отформатировать (изменить стиль на полужырный и при некоторых условиях подчеркнуть). Но проблема в формуле, при которой `ActiveCell.Characters(ind, lenght).Font.Bold = True` срабатывает для формулы, а не значения. **Формулу значением заменять нельзя!!!**
1. Нужно при обновлении данных в ячейке(ах) указанного диапазона заново применять форматирование, указанное в п.1

Comment: *Нужно часть текста ячейки, полученного с помощью формулы* Значение в ячейке - либо литерал (отображается как введено), либо формула (вычисляется, начинается со знака равенства). Половина так, половина эдак - не бывает.

Comment: ActiveCell.Characters не работает с формулами, я думаю вам лучше сделать к примеру столбец D5:D550 - куда тем же макросом скопировать значения столбца С (.Value) и его уже форматировать а столбец С скрыть

Comment: ОК. Как повесить макрос на изменение столбца? Т.е. чтобы он выполнялся только при изменении результата работы формулы?